# Unable to Get user Email address In meteor 1.9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined

when I am using `Meteor.user().emails[0].address`
my Approach following

1. `const currentUserEmail = Meteor.user.emails[0].address;`

`console.log(currentUSerEmail)`

2. ````
   const email = user.emails[0].address;
   console.log(email);```
   ````

I'm Using Meteor 1.9 With React 16.12

[I'm Using the same thing In Browser Console, here is the snap of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NX7W.png)

Its Nit working  anywhere and i also disable `autopublish` and `insecure` but nothing change

Thank  You In Advance ... Peace

Comment: 2. const user = Meteor.user();
const email = user.emails[0].address;
console.log(email);

Correction In Question LOL

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access the user before you login or before the initial publication is ready.

If you are already logged in try to access the user when Meteor.loggingIn() is true.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn

Comment: I'm Already Login I'm Able to access ```Meteor.userId()```  But Not user Email

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("AllData", Database.find({}).fetch());
}
// On Server
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish("AllData", () => {
    return Database.find();
  });
}

here is my Publication

Comment: `if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.subscribe("AllData", Database.find({}).fetch());

}

// On Server

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  // This code only runs on the server

  Meteor.publish("AllData", () => {

    return Database.find();

  });

}`

Comment: Please share the file where you are calling the Meteor.user() code so I can help you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1corU6YxvEK6-Pqs_eHxs0JOCZXtjxl9_6FvBYhFb1cI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1corU6YxvEK6-Pqs_eHxs0JOCZXtjxl9_6FvBYhFb1cI/edit?usp=sharing